# How to know your built-in webcam specification and functionalities (security related)?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, security, webcam

I've made series of pentests in my network and one of the things I've tried was record webcam and microphone. Recording microphone seems for final users a stealth thing. But what about the webcam? In my tests, the indicator is turned on and I can't figure out a way to do this without turn on the light.

So far I'm assuming that if someone break into my computer and turn on the webcam, I'll know that. But, since it's possible to avoid the light through firmware change, which technique should I use to detect the webcam use?

It's a built-in Microsoft USB 2.0 Camera, using Driver 6.1.7601.17586 on a Gigabyte W566U Notebook; running Windows 7 Professional 64 bits.

I guess to be prone I need something hardware specific.

Comment: this doesn't really answer your question, but if you're worried about someone hacking your computer and spying on you with your webcam then use some masking tape to cover the camera lens. it'll come off easily when you want to use the camera and you can reapply it when not.

Comment: @Xantec I know. But I'm interested in the detection methods, also for learning purposes. Thank you anyway.

Comment: When a webcam is in use, the light turns on, when there is a light at least. If your webcam doesn't have a light, you might need other methods, but knowing your OS would help to know.

Comment: @MaQleod Actually the light can be avoided through firmware change.

Comment: That would probably depend on the camera.

Comment: What operating system, and if possible, what camera - or at least what laptop model? We don't have any possible way to tell you system specific ways of detecting things like that without knowing anything about your environment.

Comment: @MaQleod I've updated the question with the info